# I can't find in the id of a new record from the server to update the ember model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this action. Data comes from a form after a createRecord, and it is saved perfectly in the database.

```
App.ShowController = Ember.Controller.extend({
actions: {
    createShow: function() {
        var self = this;

        var onSuccess = function(res) {
            alert('CREATED OK ' + res.get('alias'));
        };

        var onFail = function() {
            alert('err ' + res);
        };

       self.get('model').save().then(onSuccess, onFail);
    }
}
```

});

The id is generated in the database (Postgres), and I return it in a perfectly formatted json response from the app (made in Mojolicious) `{"serverResponses":{"last_id":"500"}}` along with a '200' status.

I can see the network response in the console, with the json data.

But how can I access the last_id value in the callback function onSuccess????

In "res" I have the original data I sent to the server, but, obviously its "id" attribute is undefined.

My idea es to "set" the returned id from the database in the "id" of the model.

I have seen a lot of questions about the returning format of the son, serialize problems, and so on, but what I really want to know is WHERE, in WHICH variable or object is the returned data?

Obviously, in case of Fail, I have the same problema. I return a perfectly formatted json with root for ember, but can't find it in the callback function onFail.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure properly your model, for example if you have an x model inside your controller create show action

```
//create your model locally
//acquisition is for the name of your model
//product_id is just whatever attributes you declare in your model spec
var newAcquisition = this.store.createRecord('acquisition', {
  'product_id': this.get('id'),
});

//with save it calls to the server and creates the new model and retrieves a response
newAcquisition.save().then(function(response){
    console.log('success - json '+response);   
}, function(response){
    console.log('fail - err '+response); 
});
```

After this, you don't need to catch response to put and id, if your json response is correct, Ember will handle that response and update your newly created object with that new ID

You can save data in route to controller in setupController function

```
App.ShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model){
        //setup form data
        controller.set('formData', data);
    },
    actions:{
    }
});
```

Comment: If I do the "createRecord" inside the controller, the record has not the form data. That is why I created it in the routes. I do not know how to add the form data if I create the record locally…

Comment: Have you tried setting it up with setupController inside the router ? this way you can access it within the controller

Comment: Also, the json you return must be in an format ember can read, so it can handle response automatically and do everything for you, if its not the case, you probably would need to create a custom serializer for your model

Answer (score 0):

When you create the record on the server you can return the json of the record, including ID (the same way you would return the json for a GET request). Ember data will then automatically use that response to update the model in its store. Then the argument passed to onSuccess will contain the updated model with the generated ID.

If it's not possible to change the REST api, you'll have to look into extending [RESTSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html) to extract the id from the payload.

Comment: The REST service only returns the last id, not the whole record.